# SPF, Domainkey, DKIM do not work in plesk 12

Tags: email, plesk, spf, dkim

I followed tons of online tutorials, guides and even the post here about setting up SPF records in Plesk 11.

I'm using plesk 12 on Ubuntu 12. I have set the following:

```
*.webmail.gecab.nl. CNAME   gecab.nl.
85.214.211.10 / 24  PTR gecab.nl.
_domainkey.gecab.nl.    TXT o=-
default._domainkey.gecab.nl.    TXT p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDKzW2VeEOVrpxoAw8VSW+W6tmylhdJDCiIbBu24B9/+qbkvK6VZl3dO5GvrsMiarM40fxMVlAtr47ccBWOy53KsKK+ACfxiN3FB0VIsrbKM2OtBQul6Q9GHN9FfojhHauCWOKIJBV/H5DYfeYAQPDZHbfcYOVbUKnR3rDvYHbnjwIDAQAB;
dev.gecab.nl.   A   85.214.211.10
ftp.gecab.nl.   CNAME   gecab.nl.
gecab.nl.   NS  ns.gecab.nl.
gecab.nl.   A   85.214.211.10
gecab.nl.   MX (10) mail.gecab.nl.
gecab.nl.   TXT v=spf1 ip4:85.214.211.10 -all
ipv4.gecab.nl.  A   85.214.211.10
mail._domainkey.gecab.nl.   TXT v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDC2wGgC7itM7IRnrYG6EbfY9OxZwqlGUfChLprKfCZaVBY6R9MSvTn+4RrftOlWDjDhDfC0IuuRmLuZm7KifZE7+qA2s9i1varZqTXVtITksLNSy39Bhb9IHj74UwPKRhT7bGMbKYVr5ScQ1LYbw1zRHqfyzeBDtkqZfkzKFpU8QIDAQAB
mail.gecab.nl.  A   85.214.211.10
ns.gecab.nl.    A   85.214.211.10
webmail.gecab.nl.   A   85.214.211.10
www.gecab.nl.   CNAME   gecab.nl.
```

I have also tried:

```
v=spf1 ip4:85.214.211.10 ?all
v=spf1 ip4:85.214.211.10 +mx +a -all
v=spf1 ip4:85.214.211.10 +mx +a ?all
```

I also got errors with the Domainkey record and DKIM. Both saying key can not be found. (changes are made more than 48 hours ago).

Comment: Are these from an actual zone file on copied from Plesk's web based UI? In the zone file, contents of TXT records should be inside quotation marks.

Answer (score 2):

You've probably set your DNS records in Plesk, This won't work because your DNS is set to ns.stratoserver.net.
Login to your account @ strato and set your records there.
You can copy the SPF and DKIM records from Plesk to the Strato DNS.